# including angular bootstrap ui on angular 1.3.0 project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angular.js version 1.3.0 and have the included the angular bootstrap ui in the index.html as below:

```
<script src="lib/onsen/js/angular/angular.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.1/i18n/angular-locale_en-gb.js"></script>
<script src="lib/onsen/js/onsenui.js"></script> 
<script src="js/ui-bootstrap-0.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
```

When I serve my app through gulp, I get the following error messages:

```
www\js\ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.1.min.js
line 8  col 1617  Expected '{' and instead saw 'if'.
line 8  col 1640  Expected '{' and instead saw 'return'.
line 8  col 1651  Missing semicolon.
line 8  col 1823  Missing semicolon.
line 8  col 1825  Missing semicolon.
line 8  col 1968  Missing semicolon.
line 8  col 2048  Missing semicolon.
line 8  col 2059  Missing semicolon.
line 8  col 2416  Missing semicolon.
line 8  col 2608  Missing semicolon.
line 8  col 2614  'e' is already defined.
line 8  col 2660  Missing semicolon.
line 8  col 2780  Missing semicolon.
.....
.....
line 8  col 9980  Too many errors. (80% scanned).

× 101 problems
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Angular bootstrap requires AngularJS 1.2.x

Comment: I read so too but when googling to find a solution, I came across examples running on 1.3.x. Here's one: http://plnkr.co/edit/b8BvCLDCPhjQkRlV0x85?p=preview

Comment: Here's what I intend to do in my app: http://plnkr.co/edit/XEmV9xVjRSxLcihwodQs

Comment: Your demo seems to work fine. Try to use the un-minified version of the angular bootstrap JS.

Comment: That worked! Thanks for taking your time

Answer (score 1):

Like your are using angular gulp and want to add bootstrap without any pain and any problems, i definitely recommend you to use this way to make work perfectly all the things you need.

https://github.com/Swiip/generator-gulp-angular

It will ask you during installation which version of bootstrap you want to start with.
Give it a try, i'm using it without any problems. Don't forget to valid and up vote my answer ;)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I already solved this by using the unminified version. I'll try your approach later and let you know results though, we all look for better ways to code right?

Answer (score 0):

Delete row `<script src="js/ui-bootstrap-0.12.1.min.js"></script>`